# How to plot peak array on top of another signal in Java?

Tags: java, android, graph

I have an ECG signal and the R-peaks of that signal stored in an array in my Java application. The peaks are given as the sample index of the ECG signal.

I want to plot the ECG with the peaks marked in another color. My current code only shows the ECG curve, but the peaks are nowhere to be seen. It doesn't give any error but something must be wrong

```
 public void ConfigureGraph() {
   final GraphView graph = findViewById(R.id.graphview);
   graph.getViewport().setScalable(true);

    LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> series1 = new LineGraphSeries<>();
    LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> series2 = new LineGraphSeries<>();

   series1.setDrawDataPoints(true);
   series2.setDrawDataPoints(true);
   series2.setDataPointsRadius(10);
   series2.setThickness(8);

   ArrayList<Double> myDatan=readFileNorm(); //This is my ECG
   LinkedList<Integer> myPeaks= PanTompkins.findPeaks(myDatan); //Those are my peaks

   int numberofdatapoints = 20000;
   double x=0;
   double y;

   for(int i=0; i<numberofdatapoints; i++){ //Plot the ECG
       x = x + 0.004;
       y = myDatan.get(i);
       series1.appendData(new DataPoint(x,y),true,20000);

       for(int p=0; p<myPeaks.size(); p++) { //Add the peaks to plot
           if(y == myPeaks.get(p)){
               series2.appendData(new DataPoint(x,y),true,20000);
           }
       }
   }

   graph.addSeries(series1);
   graph.addSeries(series2);
}
```

The ECG is seen here, and I have looked at the array of peaks and it looks like it should work. The first peak index is 54, which fits with the peak at 54*0.004 = 0.216; and the next is at 193*0.004=0.772.

[image: result]

Comment: Btw, I thought about dropping the for loop within the for loop, and just plotting the peaks by themselves - but I somehow needed the x-axis to match with that of the ECG. If you have any idea on how to do this in an easier way, please do tell!

Comment: You could replace the inner loop with a `Set`. So you could add `Set<Integer> peakSet = new HashSet<>(myPeaks);` below the line where you compute the peaks. Then you could replace the inner loop with
`if (peakSet.contains(y)) {
    series2.appendData(new DataPoint(x,y),true,20000);
}`. This essentially does the same as your code, but the HashSet is build, such that the `contains` check is very fast. Also the code is a bit clearer if the inner loop goes away.
For your actual question i cannot provide an answer, but it would be a good idea to mention the library you are using.